# What is a vectorized way to detect feature drift in python/pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, feature-engineering, drift

I'm working on very large pandas dataframes that hold time series with significant feature drift. The drift is often sudden (e.g., the features would be 1.5-2.0x times larger than a few periods earlier).

I found several solutions to detect 'concept drift'. One convenient option is [river](https://riverml.xyz/0.9.0/examples/concept-drift-detection/). However, the solution is not vectorized.

Clearly, vectorized approaches are much, much faster - the easiest for example using the pandas built-ins to take moving averages and look whether those change/jump `df.groupby().mean().rolling()`.

What are vectorized ways to handle the above task?

Answer (score 0):

One vectorized way to detect differences between successive rows is `df[col].diff()`. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html

If you need to look at this inside known windows, you could perhaps combine this with a rolling average and threshold:

```
df[col].diff().rolling(window=5).mean() > threshold
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the kind of "do-it-yourself" coding I would want to avoid.... for instance median jumps are likely a more robust indicator than mean jumps, and then why rolling window == 5, and what should the threshold be... Isn't there a lib for that?